# Storybook docs don't pull component propTypes automatically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook, monorepo, turborepo

Storybook docs don't pull the TypeScript propTypes automatically in a monorepo project. React docgen does not do the trick either. The expected result is to see the "description" column filled with the propTypes, but it's empty instead. Also, if you don't specify the args/argTypes, the "control" column always treats the prop as an object instead of pulling the type from the component.

I'm using the [suggested design system starter from Turbo](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/design-system).

[Live demo here](https://turborepo-examples-designsystem-docs.vercel.sh/?path=/docs/button--docs)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxc14.png)

Behaviour is consistent between different bundlers (Vite and Tsup).
Any idea of what could be wrong with this setup?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.